# Absolute variable as dependent variable

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, nonparametric

I have the following model:
$$
|X| = B_0 +B_1 \cdot y + B_2 \cdot z ,
$$
where $z$ and $y$ are normally distributed random variables, and $B_1$ and $B_2$ denote the coefficients.

My dependent variable contains either the positive or negative values of $X$. The positive and negative values of $X$ together are normally distributed, with a mean and median of around zero. For statistical reasons I would like to separately test the positive and negative values. This splits the left and right side of the otherwise normally distributed variable $X$. This clearly violates the normality assumption used for linear regression models. If I want to compare groups I would use a nonparametric type of test, but in this case I want to run the equivalent of a linear regression.  Is this possible?

Comment: The normal distribution is symmetric, so you only need a solution for one case.

Comment: I presume you mean with one case it is either positive or negative.

Comment: Yes, maybe could you further elaborate what you want to test, and in which setting?

Comment: The reason y and z need to be separated into positive and negative values is, because I expect that y and z will react differently when x is positive or negative.

Comment: Regression does not assume that the DV is normally distributed.

Comment: It is difficult, if not impossible, to formulate a legitimate statistical model based on this information. Could you please explain the context of this question and the basis for your suppositions about $X$?

Comment: If you're interested in considering the relationship for the positive and the negative X for approximately normal, mean-near-0 data, might you consider a quantile regression, where you look at say the 25-50-75 or 16-50-84  percentiles (or a number of other possibilities, depending on what you need). It's not really the same thing, but it might be closer than your suggestion to what you seem to be after. You can fit linear regressions that don't assume normality; there are a number of possibilities for that.

Comment: this reminds me of people trying to estimate logarithmized directed dyadic trade flows. Is your problem analogous?

Comment: "For statistical reasons I would like to separately test the positive and negative values" - what are these reasons? I'm afraid you are trying to formulate the problem that you dont need to solve

Comment: @Aksakal this question is more than one year old. At the time I was doing an empirical study for which I had developed multiple hypotheses which required me to split the positive from the negative values. I didn't elaborate further on my research, because this would over complicate matters.

Comment: Is it possible to restate the model?  As it stands it doesn't make a lot of sense since the left side is nonnegative but the right side can be negative.

Comment: @dsaxton, see comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can run a regression with $X_+$ and $X_-$ as independents, long as you assume a linear relationship to $Y$.

The "normality assumption" for linear regression is only regarding the error term assumed normally distributed around the true value.

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately I got results that were insignificant.

Comment: It may be the case, that linear regression is the wrong model then. Linear regression assumes a purely linear relationship. You may think of just plotting X vs. Y, to see if their relationship is linear.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean the results are wrong or that the wrong technique was used.

Comment: By $X_+$ you mean a dummy variable for when $X$ is positive correct? Given the OP's comments, I would suggest a paramterization that includes the interactions with *one* dummy (you can't include both as the are collinear unless you do not include the intercept).

Comment: The relationship between X and y has been established before in prior research and is a linear relation. With regard to z there is also evidence of a linear relationship. I was wondering if the problem was with the separation of positive and negative values.

Comment: The separation would change the probability distribution, but the relationship of X and Y may still be linear, for example if Y=aX, X can have any distribution long as its linear to Y.

Comment: @AndyW I not sure but I think emcor means running the regression once for positive values and once for negative values. So, not in one go with a dummy.

Comment: I understand we want to regress $[Y=a+bX_++cX_-+e]$ or can you please write the equation? And I understand $X_+$ not be a dummy but positive realvalued?

Comment: What would the X dummy add. Let's say X+ is significant what would this then do? Or do I need to use an interaction term for z and y to give it meaning?

Comment: Assuming that the dependent variable takes, say, only positive values, makes your model a "limited dependent variable" model (here it looks like the "truncated" sub-family of such models. This needs special treatment. Look up the term in the econometrics literature. You can start from this downloadable .pdf : www.econ.pdx.edu/faculty/KPL/readings/dhrymes.pdf

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I can across truncated data, but I wasn't sure if that could be the answer. I will look into it.

Comment: Implicitly the model is $|X|=B_1y+B_2z+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is random error. Under usual assumptions (such as a zero expectation for $\epsilon$) this means that some of the positive $X$ really come from the model for truly negative values and *vice versa*. Therefore either adding a dummy based on the sign of $X$ or splitting the data according to the sign of $X$ will be invalid (although conceivably it might be a decent approximation).